# MDX and SSAS - Subtotal on Filtering in Power BI

Tags: ssas, mdx, powerbi

I have a sales cube deployed in SSAS that need to be displayed using Power BI. Assume that I have arrange a layout – simulated with Excel - like the following, a dimension (Product - with 5 members) and two Measures (Measures 1 and Measures 2).

[image: Initial Layout]

Measures 3 is a calculated member
([Measures].[Measures 1], [Product].CurrentMember.Parent)*[Measures].[Measure 2]

If viewed in Excel, the calculation in Excel will be something like this.

[image: The calculation]

And then user can filter Product on any data point, simulated below with A, B, and C as product filtering and produce value below.

[image: Layout after filtering]

This is where I have no clue on how to get the grand total of measures with filters, like the yellow columns. What should I know to achieve this?

Comment: Is your SSAS in Tabular or Multidimensional mode?

Comment: Hi @RADO, it is in Multidimensional mode

Comment: Hi Dino-

If I'm interpreting your question right, the problem comes when the product table is filtered, because the filter will not respect your want to see all values.

In this case, if you were using Tabular, you'd want to use SumX on the Measure1, and the multiply by Measure2. I'm not sure that MD SSAS will allow you to add that as a Measure in the PowerBI side.

Comment: Hi Frostytheswimmer, yes you are interpreting me right. Well noted for he clue. Thank you for the response.